# Elixir Try Catch

Tags: elixir

I am trying to figure out a scoping issue. I have a procedural function that is setting up a bunch of related resources on AWS. I need to be able to catch a failure and rollback all the relations that have been setup. I have a try catch setup, but the variables that are in the try block are not available in the catch, I need them so I can take the correct steps to rollback.

```
try do
  c = connection
  cert = aws.cert
  module = aws.create_mod(cert)
  etc...
rescue
  :error ->
      rollback(c, cert, module)
end
```

any advice about how to handle this?

Comment: Seriously - - do this via a gen_server.  Spin up the resources in a process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Elixir cannot guarantee that those variables will be set by the time an exception is raised. This may not be the case for you, but imagine something like this.

```
try do
  foo = do_something_safe()
  bar = do_something_that_will_raise_an_error()
  baz = do_something_else_safe()
  ...
rescue
  RuntimeError ->
    quux(foo, baz)
end
```

In the previous example, the call to `do_something_that_will_raise_an_error()` will raise an error. Both `bar` and `baz` will not be set because of it.

In this specific case, you may be able to do something like

```
baz = do_something_else_safe()
foo = do_something_safe()
try do
  bar = do_something_that_will_raise_an_error()
  ...
rescue
  RuntimeError ->
    quux(foo, baz)
end
```

Now, even if the call to `do_something_that_will_raise_an_error()` raises the error, you still have the `foo`, and `baz` variables set, and they can be used in the rescue block.

Basically, setup the variables that you can outside of the `try`. [This](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html#variables-scope) gives a nice little overview of the variable scope inside of a `try ... rescue`.

With that in mind, it might be better to setup a supervisor and do this inside of a `GenServer` (Or any other supervised process really). That way, if it crashes, the supervisor can decide what to do with it. Both Elixir and Erlang are of the mindset "let it crash" instead of trying to program defensively.